# Error while trying to create a database for SSRS

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssrs, sql-server-2017

I have installed SQL Server Reporting Services 2017, and my database engine is developer edition 2017. Now, while trying to configure SSRS from its Configuration Manager I get this error

[image]

I have found some really scarce online resources about this error which does not solve my problem.

I need help in figuring out what I should do? Do I need another edition of SQL Server database engine?

Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64)   Jul 21 2018 07:47:45   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0  (Build 17134: )

I've downloaded SSRS from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252

clicking the link provided in Developer Edtion setup.exe

SSRS Version: 14.0.600.892, Native mode

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you connecting to the same SQL Server instance where the Reporting Services are located / have been installed? Everything is on one server, right? _SQL Server Instance, SQL Server Database, Reporting Services, Reporting Server Databases (being created...)_

Comment: It's only supported in Standard and Enterprise editions.. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998070/ssrs-2014-database-setup-error-using-other-editions-of-sql-server-for-report

Comment: So, means I can't use SSRS for Developer edition? @CR241

Comment: That's not quite right. Developer Edition has the same Enterprise Edition Engine as, well, the Enterprise Editions does. SQL Server Reporting Services runs on a Developer Edition. I am currently looking at a connected Reporting Services instance in my local Developer Edition. So it should be working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed SQL Server 2017 side-by-side with an existing SQL Server 2014 instance.

I installed SQL Server Reporting Services 2017 as per the download link.

During the installation I was asked which edition of SSRS I would like to install. The options were:

- Developer Edition
- Evaluation Edition (180 days)
- Express Edition

I selected Developer Edition and everything worked fine.

---

## Mixed Editions

If I install the SSRS as an **Express Edition**, then the configuration of the SSRS datbase will fail with the mentioned error message:

[image: Report Services Configuration Manager]

## Solution

You have to install the SSRS 2017 using the same Edition as your SQL Server 2017 Edition.

- If you are running SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition then you have to install SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services with the option **Developer Edition**.
- If you are running SQL Server 2017 Evaluation Edition then you have to install SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services with the option **Evaluation Edition**.
- If you are running SQL Server 2017 Express Edition then you have to install SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services with the option **Express Edition**.

You will have to de-install your current SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services and ensure you install the identical Edition.

---

## SSRS 2017 Developer Edition with SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition

I had no issues installing SSRS 2017 Developer Edition with SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition.

### SSRS Setup Step 1

[image: SSRS Setup Step 1]

### SSRS Setup Step 2

[image: SSRS Setup Step 2]

### SSRS Setup Step 3

[image: SSRS Setup Step 3]

### SSRS Setup Step 4

[image: SSRS Setup Step 4]

### SSRS Setup Step 5

[image: SSRS Setup Step 5]

### SSRS Setup Step 6

[image: SSRS Setup Step 6]

### SSRS Setup Step 7

[image: SSRS Setup Step 7]

If the editions match, then you won't have any issues. 
If the editions don't match, then you will encounter the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using developer edition then pull down the combo box and select developer. The box appeared to already say developer but it was not.